# How to properly deal with NaNs in Tensorflow model

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I am currently training a Tensorflow model which has various values and features filled with NaN. For example:

```
feature = [np.Nan, 'foo', 'foo', np.Nan, 'bar', 'foo']
```

Tensorflow doesn't deal with NaN values, so I replaced them 0:

```
feature = [0 'foo', 'foo', 0, 'bar', 'foo']
```

But of course Tensorflow doesn't deal with mixed tensors. What I really want to do is have the model ignore these inputs when training a neural network model.

But since I'm working with `tf.feature_columns`, I don't have the freedom to feed these inputs directly in the model because I need to explicitly state if they are strings or ints when using `tf.categorical` and `tf.numeric_column` methods.

Any suggestions for working with types of feature columns? I would much prefer to stick with `tf.feature_columns` if possible.

Comment: You the standard NLP approach : a fixed term (e.g., `"<UNK>"` or `"<NaN>"`) to denote these values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Susmit mostly answered the question in the comments, for completeness: to "ignore" the value you could use the data as your vocabulary without NaN and the `"<UNK>"` lookup would return -1.

```
na_mask = np.isna(feature)
vocab = np.unique(feature[~na_mask])
feature[na_mask] = "<UNK>"
...
tf.feature_column.categorical_column_with_vocabulary_list("feature", vocab)
```

Comment: So just to be clear: you seem to be ignoring the NaNs using ~na_mask, and then you are replacing all the NaNs with "<UNK>". When you setup tf.categorical, you are not passing in the NaNs at all because they are not in the vocabulary. Did I follow your code correctly?